# Улетел перевод вопросов

Tags: дефект, локализация, список-вопросов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему скриншот можно обрезать, а то я даже не сразу заметил, что улетело-то

Comment: Вы можете сами предлагать переводы на ru.traducir.win

Comment: @älёxölüt я не могу на него зайти, хотя использую обход блокировки